# Natural but scientific ways to improve memory and concentration

Tags: research, memory, concentration, brain-exercises

There's a lot of websites on internet that claim a number of games, exercises and diets to be actually helpful in this regard but they do not provide any authentic citation. Some of them are complementary while few are contradictory.

I'm confused and really don't understand which tips are most thoroughly updated according to research.

---

UPDATE 1

I recently read [articles.mercola.com](http://www.mercola.com/forms/background.htm). It appeared pretty authentic because the author is an active researcher.

---

UPDATE 2

By natural I mean non-medicinal means like Exercises, diets and games. I'm looking for them because I'm already under medication and wish to try something non-medicinal for recovery.

**P.S.**  I'm new so guide me to improve this question.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). This is a very interesting question, but it appears rather broad to me. It might be better if you could specify the methods that you would like to get the answers about. Or are you asking for any method substantiated by scientific research? Also, I don't see how the link you provided relates to your question. If you could link the specific page about memory and concentration exercises, that would help. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucky I've edited the title to make it more precise. By scientific ways I mean natural ways that are scientifically approved. Besides the link does not open any article about concentration or memory but about the author writing the website who seems to be an active researcher. I linked it to know all your opinions .

Comment: define "natural"

Comment: @JJosaur By natural I mean non-medicinal means.

Comment: Would you say aspirin is medicinal?

Comment: @JJosaur Yes I do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question falls foul of the asker Appealing to Nature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_nature

Comment: FYI, asprin is a 400 year old "natural" remedy, it was discovered from the bark of the willow tree. Alternative (commonly referred to as 'natural') medicine that has been proven to work is just called "Medicine".

Comment: @JJosaur I've made some edits. May now my post is no longer misleading.

Comment: Some sages say that mind is like a muscle, the more you use it, the more memory you develop, so [puzzles are good for it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com). For improving concentration, one can try meditation.